# もう + た-form AND た-form + こと が ある

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two sentences?

寿司をもう食べた

寿司を食べたことがある

Both sentences mean "I've already eaten sushi", right? But what situation would I use もう食べた in? And when would I use 食べたことがある?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) 「寿司{すし}を食{た}べたことがある。」
>
> 2) 「寿司をもう食べた。」

The first sentence can only mean one thing and **the second can mean two very different things**.

1) can only mean "**I have eaten sushi before**."  This person has already experienced eating sushi.  The speaker, therefore, would almost always be a non-Japanese person.

2) can mean the exact same as 1) and an additional thing, which is:

"I have already eaten ***the*** sushi."

**The meal happened to be sushi that time**.  Thus, for this meaning, the speaker can well be a Japanese person.